# How to check if Class is Compiler Generated

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, system.reflection

I would like a method to check if a type is an Auto Generated type by the C# compiler (e.g. Lambda Closures, Actions, Nested Methods, Anonymous Types, etc).

Currently have the following:

```cs
public bool IsCompilerGenerated(Type type)
{
    return type.Name.StartsWith("<>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

With accompanying test:

```cs
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        class SomeInnerClass
        {

        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            // Arrange - Create Compiler Generated Nested Type
            var test = "test";

            void Act() => _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Inside Action: " + test);

            // Arrange - Prevent Compiler Optimizations
            test = "";
            Act();

            var compilerGeneratedTypes = GetType().Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Display")) // Name of compiler generated class == "<>c__DisplayClass5_0"
                .ToList();

            Assert.False(IsCompilerGenerated(typeof(SomeInnerClass)));

            Assert.NotEmpty(compilerGeneratedTypes);
            Assert.All(compilerGeneratedTypes, type => Assert.True(IsCompilerGenerated(type)));
        }
    }
```

Is there any better way to check for compiler generated types rather than the name?

Comment: Check if the type has a CustomAttribute of type [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8).  I have not verified that all compiler generated types so decorated, but I know closures are and would bet the same applies for the others as well.

Comment: That looks perfect, looks like exactly what I'm looking for! Feel feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that Microsoft follows their own guidance for application of the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8),

> Remarks
>
> Apply the CompilerGeneratedAttribute attribute to any application
>   element to indicate that the element is generated by a compiler.
>
> Use the CompilerGeneratedAttribute attribute to determine whether an
>   element is added by a compiler or authored directly in source code.

you can check the type's CustomAttributes to determine if the type is so decorated with something like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

public bool IsCompilerGenerated(Type type)
{
    return type.GetCustomAttribute<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null;
}
```